# How to prevent duplicated sections in taglist with vim-latex

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vim-latex, plugin-taglist

The plugin [yegappan/taglist](https://github.com/yegappan/taglist) and the plugin [vim-latex](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) are very nice to navigate within the table of content of a latex document. There is an issue however on my system section titles are duplicated. Example based on [minimal latex](https://gist.github.com/Michael0x2a/e46e12a66b7dc604db5e).

[image]

If I disable the vim-latex plugin, the taglist appears without repetitions, but it has less details on figure and table references and it is missing some subsubsections.

- How to prevent duplicated section titles in the taglist pane?

**Update with additional information**:

- Link to my [~/.vimrc](https://gist.github.com/paulrougieux/e02ee2c501ee5d8b2537d1ac9f1fe68b)
- Link to [issue 178 reported on vim-latex](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/issues/178)
- `:verbose set tags?` shows `tags=./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS`

**Updated question:**

- I'd like to keep only tags generated by vim-latex. How to disable definitions generated externally?

Comment: Bonsoir Paul. I'm not quite sure how to fix this, however I think you should clarify the way you generate your tags, this might help others help you better. A link to the plugin would also be great. Is it [this one](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex)?

Comment: Does it change if you use `\section` instead of `\section*`?

Comment: Maybe bring this up on the Issues page of both the respective projects? Surely they must have git repos?

Comment: Since you're not building your tags *a la mano*, there's nothing much we can do, unless you've done something wrong with your config. If that could be the case, you can update your post with your config.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yes it also happens with `\section`.

Comment: @TejasSanap I posted [an issue on vim-latex](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/issues/178) since it seems more related to that plugin. Ctags in other languages such as python appear ok in the taglist.

Answer (score 1):

I now use the [vimtex plugin](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/) with the `:VimtexTocOpen` command to open a table of content for latex files.

See also `:help vimtex-nf-tag-nav`:

> One may navigate by tags with the `|CTRL-]|` mapping, e.g. from
> `\eqref{eq:example}` to the corresponding `\label{eq:example}`. However,
> this requires that a tag file has been generated with `|ctags|`. I recommend
> that one uses the maintained version of [ctags](https://ctags.io/). In addition,
> I recommend that one uses a plugin that automatically generates the tag
> files as necessary, e.g. [gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags).
> See `|vimtex-faq-tags|` and `|vimtex-faq-tags-bibtex|` for concrete examples.